# Disable Increased Indentation on Open Brackets, Parentheses, Quotes, etc

Tags: interface

An interface annoyance, to the otherwise exceptional automatic indentation, is the fact that Mathematica increases the indentation on a line when one opens a bracket, parentheses, quote, etc.

I can't seem to find a way to disable only this feature. Although disabling the automatic indentation as a whole is straightforward, either through the option inspector or the preferences, disabling the described feature is not.

I have noticed (thanks to a friend) that in Wolfram Workbench such an option exists, as can be seen here:
http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/preferences/indenting.html
 (option: extra indent after open)